# APP in localhost works, but in deploy didn't works

Tags: javascript, express, deployment, render

My code works in localhost, but when i try deploy in render.com doesn't works. Follow above the codes and log. Same files is in same folder.

File: userModel.js

```
const User = require('./User')

const getUserByEmail = async(email) =>{
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({email})
        return user
    }catch(err){        
        throw new Error("Ocorreu um erro no servidor")
    }
}
const createUser = async(firstName,lastName,email,passwordHash)=>{
    try{
        const user = await User({firstName,lastName,email,password:passwordHash,failedAttempts: 0,blockTimestamp: 0})
        await user.save()
    }catch(err){        
        throw new Error("Ocorreu um erro no servidor")
    }
}
const blockUser = async(user)=>{
    user.blockTimestamp = Date.now() + 300000  
    await user.save()  
}
const inscraseFailedAttempts = async(user)=>{
    user.failedAttempts = user.failedAttempts + 1;
    await user.save() 
}
const desblockUser = async(user)=>{
    try{
        user.failedAttempts = 0
        user.blockTimestamp = 0
        await user.save() 
    }catch(err){        
        throw new Error('Ocorreu um erro no servidor ao tentar desbloquear o usuário')
    }
}
module.exports= {
    getUserByEmail,
    createUser,
    blockUser,
    inscraseFailedAttempts,
    desblockUser
}
```

File: User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    failedAttempts: Number,
    blockTimestamp: Number, 
})
const User = mongoose.model('User', schema)

module.exports = User
```

Logs from render:

Mar 14 09:11:24 PM  ==> Starting service with 'npm start'

Mar 14 09:11:27 PM

Mar 14 09:11:27 PM  > login_schedule@1.0.0 start /opt/render/project/src

Mar 14 09:11:27 PM  > cross-env ISDEV=true node ./src/app.js

Mar 14 09:11:27 PM

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM    throw err;

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM    ^

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  Error: Cannot find module './User'

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  Require stack:

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/model/userModel.Js

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/controller/registerUserController.js

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/router.js

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/src/app.js

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/src/model/userModel.Js:1:14)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM    requireStack: [

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/src/model/userModel.Js',

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/src/controller/registerUserController.js',

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/src/router.js',

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/src/app.js'

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM    ]

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  }

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! errno 1

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! login_schedule@1.0.0 start: `cross-env ISDEV=true node ./src/app.js`

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR!

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the login_schedule@1.0.0 start script.

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Mar 14 09:11:33 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-03-15T00_11_33_673Z-debug.log

Comment: Which part of this error `Mar 14 09:11:33 PM Error: Cannot find module './User'` is not clear?

Comment: I understand that is a problem. But, why this code ```const User = require('./User')``` don't work to solve ?

Comment: Well, apparently the module you want to load isn't at `./User` when you deploy.